# JQUERY Class remove issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add class(**`.sidebarActive`**) to **`.sidebarButton`** when it's clicked and remove that class from all other buttons with the same(**`.sidebarButton`**) class. The part of code which adds the active class to **`.sidebarButton`** works, however it doesn't remove the active class when other button is clicked. Any suggestions.? Is the logic of my code wrong? Thank you for you help.

```
$(".sidebarButton").click(function() {
  hideActive();
  $(this).addClass('sidebarActive');
});

function hideActive() {
    var sidebars = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebarButton");
    for (var i = 0, l = sidebars.length; i < l; i++) {
        sidebars[i].removeClass(".sidebarActive");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply remove `.sidebarActive` from every `.sidebarButton` on click then add it on the one clicked :

```
$(".sidebarButton").click(function() {
  $(".sidebarButton").removeClass('sidebarActive');
  $(this).addClass('sidebarActive');
});
```

```js
$(".sidebarButton").click(function() {
  $(".sidebarButton").removeClass('sidebarActive');
  $(this).addClass('sidebarActive');
});
```

```css
.sidebarButton{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarActive{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="sidebarButton">Test 1</p>
<p class="sidebarButton">Test 2</p>
<p class="sidebarButton">Test 3</p>
<p class="sidebarButton">Test 4</p>
```

Comment: I thought that I tried this approach but it didn't work but apparently I did something else because this works. Many thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

In your hideActive function `sidebars[i].removeClass(".sidebarActive");` doesn't work because `sidebars[i]` is not a Jquery object.

Change it to this:

```
sidebars[i].classList.remove("sidebarActive");
```

Or do what Zenoo posted for a full Jquery solution